# Can't upload files reliably in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I got this method that's intended to upload a file, but sometimes it does so when $this->imageFile is not instantiated. I have no idea why.

```
public function upload()
{

    $path = Url::to('@webroot/images/photos/');
    $filename = strtolower($this->username) . '.jpg';
    $this->imageFile->saveAs($path . $filename);


    return true;

}
```

I call the method upload() in beforeSave() like this:

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{

    if(parent::beforeSave($insert)){

        if($this->isNewRecord)
        {
            $this->password = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($this->password);
        }

        $this->upload();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I called this method like 100 times with mixed results. I have no idea why this method call doesn't give the same result. It should either never work or always work, but for some reason the code is not deterministic at all.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Member();
    $model->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFile');


    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {


        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Another thing, when I use this code, I get a file, but the username is blank so I get a .jpeg file without a name.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Member();
    $model->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFile');
    $model->upload(); 


    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {


        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: are actionCreate and upload methods in the same class ?  if not just pay attention the if clause in the actionCreate, Inside If. you are redirecting so $model is just disappear in request, but in Else you are sending $model directly to template. Incosistency may appears because of that.

Comment: No, upload is in the Member model class. I doubt that it has anything to do with the if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
} else {
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

In the If clause you are redirecting to view and `$model` disappears between requests naturally. But in else you sending `$model` to view directly. It looks like the buggy section.

The other one, when you move the `$model->upload()` to actionCreate, you are placing it before If statement but you are loading the post to the model in if clause so, naturally user wasn't loading when you are trying to upload.

If you are prefer to send `$model->upload()` to action just be sure to call following method before upload. `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())`

Comment: Actually, you're right. The question now is why their code works for them: https://github.com/mjbeaumont/packt-learning-yii-2/blob/master/Code/monstermash/controllers/MonsterController.php

Comment: If you mean this section `
/**

* Displays a single Monster model.

* @param integer $id

* @return mixed

*/

public function actionView($id)

{

return $this->render('view', [

'model' => $this->findModel($id),

]);

}

` it doesnt send İD directly it sends model through findModel

Comment: Their redirection goes to that function after redirection findModel loads Model properly